# Keycloak Metrics SPI Login Request Counts at Different Time Intervals

Tags: keycloak, prometheus, metrics

I am using Keycloak 21.0.2 with [Metrics SPI](https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi).
I would like to obtain the count of login requests per 1 minute, 1 hour, and 1 day individually, instead of aggregating them in the totalLogins parameter. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve this in my metrics?

For example having:

```
keycloak_login_attempts_per_minute{realm="myrealm",provider="keycloak",client_id="myclient",} 2.0
keycloak_login_attempts_per_hour{realm="myrealm",provider="keycloak",client_id="myclient",} 2.0
keycloak_login_attempts_per_day{realm="myrealm",provider="keycloak",client_id="myclient",} 2.0
keycloak_logins_per_minute{realm="myrealm",provider="keycloak",client_id="myclient",} 2.0
keycloak_logins_per_hour{realm="myrealm",provider="keycloak",client_id="myclient",} 2.0
keycloak_logins_per_day{realm="myrealm",provider="keycloak",client_id="myclient",} 2.0
```

Comment: Why is `increase(keycloak_login_attempts[1m])` (1h and 1d for hour and day respectively) not suitable for you?

Comment: @markalex How can I use this in my java code?

Comment: Depends on what you are asking about. Are you querying metrics from Prometheus in your java app? If so - same as any other query. If you speaking about exposition - you don't. Query I suggested is supposed to be used on "client side" (for example in Grafana)